# Custom domain on heroku

Tags: heroku, dns

I have already deployed my app on heroku
and read this as well
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#custom-subdomains
i did this step:

> $ heroku domains:add www.xyz.in
>   Adding www.xyz.in to quiet-hollows-4886... done

which was fine, but
when i do this step:

> $ host www.xyz.in
>   www.xyz.in has address 208.91.197.205

which is not the supposed result it should have been:

> $ host www.xyz.in
>   www.xyz.in is an alias for xyz.herokuapp.com

Please tell me what i'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you actually updated your DNS records. (If not - that's kind of required. Go to wherever the domain `www.xyz.in` is hosted and update the records.)

You need to wait a while for the DNS records to propogate. This is dependent on your DNS records TTL, as well as your DNS host and your local DNS server.

This can take anything from 5 minutes to 24 hours.

You can always try `dig` on `@8.8.8.8` (Google's public DNS server) which usually updates quickly.